# initializing with 'Object *__strong' an expression of incompatible type 'id<Protocol>'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, inheritance, protocols

Why does assigning an id extending a protocol to an object which also extends the same protocol produces the warning initializing with 'Object *__strong' an expression of incompatible type 'id' sometimes? I am not asking the way to suppress the warning.

```
@protocol PA <NSObject>

@end

@interface A1 : NSObject <PA>

@end

@interface A2 : NSManagedObject <PA> // Same for NSString in Xcode 8

@end



@protocol PB

@end

@interface B1 : NSObject <PB>

@end

@interface B2 : NSManagedObject <PB>

@end

A1 *a1 = (id<PA>)nil; // no warnings
A2 *a2 = (id<PA>)nil; // warning in Xcode 8. initializing with 'A2 *__strong' an expression of incompatible type 'id<PA>'

B1 *b1 = (id<PB>)nil; // warning in Xcode 8 and 7
B2 *b2 = (id<PB>)nil; // warning in Xcode 8 and 7
```

Comment: Well, it's an implicit downcast, and implicit downcasts should be warnings (or errors) -- that's the point of type checking. Not sure why the first one doesn't have a warning.

Comment: Implicit downcasting a pure id is fine. id is any type. Then what is id<Protocol>?

Comment: `id<Protocol>` is not `id`. Only `id` turns off static type checking. `id<Protocol>` does not